# IPA packing for ad-hoc or app store, test version is working

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, adobe, testflight

BASETHREADINITTHUNK()
RtlUserthreadstart()
compliation failed while executing

Hi when i tried to build add-hoc or app store version of IPA, i got this above error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cICJX.png)

Comment: It is `Android` related, not `iOS`.

Comment: but i packed it to ipa

Comment: why it show apk fail, it looks weird. I am using adobe air